# Address of Static Variables Changing at Runtime

Tags: c, linux, memory, gdb

I'm trying to figure out why the address of a `static uint64_t arr[]` changes when it's defined in the global scope inside the main executable.
It changes from `0x201060` (defined by the linker?) to `0x555555755060` at runtime, and I have no idea why.

Why does this happen, and is there a way I can prevent this behavior?

I have a precompiled binary that does not exhibit this behavior, and I am trying to emulate it.

```
$ gdb a.out   # compiled from test.c
GNU gdb (GDB) 8.0.1...
Reading symbols from a.out...done.
(gdb) x/x arr
0x201060 <arr>: 0x00000024
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x6e9: file test.c, line 116.
(gdb) run
Starting program: ... 
Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdb28) at test.c:116
116     if(argc != 2) {
(gdb) x/x arr
0x555555755060 <arr>:   0x00000024
```

`test.c` was compiled with the following options: `-g -fno-stack-protector -z execstack`.

I compiled and ran `test.c` without ASLR (`sudo bash -c 'echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space'`), but the result was the same.

The relevant parts of `test.c` are:

```
#include <stdint.h>

extern int func(uint64_t[]);

static uint64_t arr[] = {
    0x00000024, 0x00201060,
    0x00201080, 0x00000000,
    0x00000008, 0x002010e0,
    0x002010a0, 0x00000000,
    0x00000032, 0x002010c0,
    ...
    0x00201100, 0x00000000
};


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
     func(arr);
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Consider if 2 instances of the program were running.  Do you expected them both to use the same `static uint64_t arr[]`?

Comment: Why do you want to prevent this behavior?

Comment: This could be address space layout randomization.
It could also be from being mapped to a virtual memory space at runtime

Comment: @chux yes. Virtual memory will deal with memory conflicts by mapping the addresses of each of the processes into two different areas in physical memory.

Comment: When you have trouble understanding how some code works, always create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us. For example, what *is* `arr`?

Comment: What happens if you step into the assembler with GDB?
Any clues?

Comment: it may also be helpful to compare your precompiled test binary to the one you have. Sometimes these test binaries are often compiled as 32 bit which can change some stack semantics and calling conventions.

Comment: @enabrentane they are both 64-bit binaries

Comment: what is the contents of `func()`?

Comment: Why is the code exposing the 'static' array `arr[]` to another (external) function?

Comment: Please post the output of `gcc -###`. Your compiler was probably built to generate PIE executables by default.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Thank you! My version of gcc was outputting PIE executables by default, and disabling that fixed my problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out :)

It turns out my `gcc` was outputting PIE executables by default, and passing `-no-pie` did what I needed. I made the array `static` in an attempt to keep the address the same, but I suppose that `static` only keeps the address the same *during* runtime.

Thank you to Mark Plotnick for your suggestion in the comments!